# DIfferences in pictures between ie6 and ie7

Tags: internet-explorer-6, photoshop, image

```
BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(../images/feedback_trans_tab.png);

_background-image: url(../images/feedback_tab_ie6.png)
```

I've seen code like this in a css file
feedback_tab_ie6.png is 886 bytes and feedback_trans_tab.png has 1.64Kb
Both pics have transparent backgrounds so that you can apply your own background color. Both look the same. yet in IE6 if I comment this line:

```
_background-image: url(../images/feedback_tab_ie6.png)
```

this appears:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1ea66ad1b8.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1ea66ad1b8.jpg)
and if I don't this appears:
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/d587c76db3.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/d587c76db3.jpg)

This happens for the same background-color value of course:

```
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #689BCA;
```

DOes anyone have any idea why this is?
How can I turn a > ie6 picture into an ie6 picture from Photoshop?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE6 there is no PNG alpha channel transparency support.

So for an image to appear partially transparent in IE6, you need a different image.

See [this](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/alpha.html) blog post about the issue.

Comment: I see, but how can I turn my regular image to a image that will display properly in IE6 from Photoshop?

Comment: See this blog from some options: http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6

Comment: It doesn't really say there how to make a ie6 transparent picture in photoshop

Comment: @Para - the link in my answer does explain it. You need to understand that a transparent PNG will _not_ work in IE6 without additional steps, as described in both links.

Comment: OK I understand this but in the example I saw. That works there were to different image files. Just like I explained above. I wanted to know how I could create an image file that displayed in IE6 the same as the creator of that example did.